# Program meant to go to a function but instead follows try and except loop

Tags: python, nameerror

I have decided to make a basic game in Python 3.3 where the a monster and a treasure is generated individually on a number from 1-100, and the user has to choose a number. The program will then inform the user if they are too close or too high or if they have hit something.

I have made a try loop with an except NameError (as I am on Mac, it would be ValueError for Windows). Before I ask anything, I would like to share with you the code that I have so far:

```
import time, random

def generateValues():
    global treasurePos, monsterPos
    while treasurePos != monsterPos:
        treasurePos = random.randint(1, 100)
        monsterPos = random.randint(1, 100)
    print(treasurePos)
    print(monsterPos)

def mainmenu():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("welcome to this game, press 1 to play or 2 to quit")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    try:
        option = int(input("What would you like to do: "))
        if option == (1):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            generateValues()
        elif option == (2):
            quit()
    except NameError:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("please enter only 1 or 2")            



mainmenu()
```

If I enter 1, my original plan was for the game to continue and generate the positons for the treasure and the monster. What the program does, instead, is loop back to this:

```
except NameError:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("please enter only 1 or 2")
```

Which further creates an infinite loop of 'please enter only 1 or 2' - even when I do enter 1.

My question is thus, is there a simple or complex command that I can do to stop this loop from continuing and to allow the program to continue to the 'generateValues' function?

I would appreciate any help or insight that you are willing to share.

Thanks in advance,
Leo

EDIT 1:

Karen Clark pointed out my while loop and I have coded an alternative solution for it below which works:

```
def generateValues():
    global treasurePos, monsterPos
    treasurePos = 0
    monsterPos = 0
    treasurePos = random.randint(1, 3)
    monsterPos = random.randint(1, 5)
    if treasurePos == monsterPos:
        generateValues()
    else:
        print(treasurePos)
        print(monsterPos)
```

Comment: I'm confused by the while loop. Is there a reason you are trying to generate the values forever? Surely a single random value for each would work...

Comment: @Karen Clark My purpose for the while loop was to generate the values until they are two different values. If the same values are generated for both positions, then the program would generate different numbers again.

Comment: I have changed it now, look at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the generateValues() function.  You need to initizalize both treasurePos and monsterPos to work. Try this:

```
def generateValues():
    global treasurePos, monsterPos
    treasurePos = 10
    monsterPos = 1
    while treasurePos != monsterPos:
        treasurePos = random.randint(1, 100)
        monsterPos = random.randint(1, 100)
    print(treasurePos)
    print(monsterPos)
```

Just make sure to give them different values. If, not the code won't enter the loop.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you a lot for this answer!

Comment: can you please look at one of the replies to my answer - I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo when calling generateCharPosition().  The function definition is correct, but the calls are missing an "i" - generateCharPos**i**tion